# Checksum File Comparison Tool

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

So I am looking for a tool that can compare files in folders based on checksums (this is common, not hard to find); however, my use-case is that the files can exist in pretty deep folder paths that can change, I am expected to compare them every few months and ONLY create a package of the different files. I don't care what folders the files are in, the same file can move between folders regularly and files wouldn't change names much, only content (so checksums are a must).

My issue is that almost all of the tools I can find do care about the folder paths when they compare folders, I don't and I actually want it to ignore the folder paths. I rather not develop anything or at least only have to develop a small part of the process to save time.

To be clear the order I am looking for things to happen are:

```
Program scans directory from 1/1/2020 (A).
Program scans directory from 4/1/2020 (B)
Finds all files where checksum in B don't exist in A and make a new folder with differences (C).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So the locations *and* file names can change?  That means the checksum/hash for every file in B must be compared to the one for every file in A.  You'll need some sort of tree or hash map to make that run in a reasonable amount of time.  If you store A in a local database with the hash / checksum field indexed a db engine will do much of the work for you.  Select returns 0 rows means it's a new file or a changed file.

Comment: Yes, each one needs to be compared. I do not believe names can change, BUT the content will and if the file is different/changed I want it. The position can/will change in the directory.
100% it will be a very tiresome brute force checksum comparison. It's only about 47gb over about 32,000 files. If it takes 6 hours, that is ok as this needs to happen once a quarter.

Honestly getting the difference is not the hard part, its taking that info and using it to copy to build directory C

Comment: This seems to be a software-recommendations question.  See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and follow [their rules for constructing a good question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I figured there would be a place for it, but didnt see it. Sorry, and thank you.